# Can't get value from function

Tags: knockout.js

***Javascript***

```
(function() {
  $(function() {
    var productChooser;
    productChooser = function() {
      this.quantity = ko.observable(0);
      this.productId = ko.observable(1);
      this.genderId = ko.observable(1);
      this.sizeId = ko.observable(1);
      this.colorId = ko.observable(1);
      this.setGenderAndSize = function(stringtoparse) {
        var values;
        console.log(stringtoparse);
        values = stringtoparse.split(":");
        alert("fasdfs");
        this.genderId(values[0]);
        this.sizeId(values[1]);
      };
    };
    return ko.applyBindings(new productChooser(), $("#genderAndSizeChooser")[0]);
  });

}).call(this);
```

***HTML***

```
<div class="btn-group" id="genderAndSizeChooser">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-size dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Size <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu sizegen-text" role="menu">
    <li class="active"><a href="">CHOOSE A SIZE...</a></li>
    <li><a data-bind='click: setGenderAndSize.bind("2:2")'>MALE XS</a></li>
    <li><a data-bind='click: setGenderAndSize.bind("2:2")'>MALE S</a></li>
    <li><a data-bind='click: setGenderAndSize.bind("2:2")'>MALE M</a></li>
    <li><a data-bind='click: setGenderAndSize.bind("2:2")'>MALE L</a></li>
    <li><a data-bind='click: setGenderAndSize.bind("2:2")'>MALE XL</a></li>
    <li><a data-bind='click: setGenderAndSize.bind("2:2")'>FEMALE XS</a></li>
    <li><a data-bind='click: setGenderAndSize.bind("2:2")'>FEMALE S</a></li>
    <li><a data-bind='click: setGenderAndSize.bind("2:2")'>FEMALE M</a></li>
    <li><a data-bind='click: setGenderAndSize.bind("2:2")'>FEMALE L</a></li>
    <li><a data-bind='click: setGenderAndSize.bind("2:2")'>FEMALE XL</a></li>      
  </ul>
</div>
```

I can't get the value from the `setGenderAndSize`. A simple `console.log(stringtoparse)` outputs the viewmodel, `productChooser {quantity: function, productId: function, genderId: function, sizeId: function, colorId: function…}`

How do I get the value passed by `setGenderAndSize`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out that you need to add the value passed is just a second argument:

```
<div class="btn-group" id="genderAndSizeChooser">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-size dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Size <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu sizegen-text" role="menu">
    <li class="active"><a href="">CHOOSE A SIZE...</a></li>
    <li><a data-bind='click: setGenderAndSize.bind($data, "2:2")'>MALE XS</a></li>
    <li><a data-bind='click: setGenderAndSize.bind($data, "2:2")'>MALE S</a></li>
    <li><a data-bind='click: setGenderAndSize.bind($data, "2:2")'>MALE M</a></li>
    <li><a data-bind='click: setGenderAndSize.bind($data, "2:2")'>MALE L</a></li>
    <li><a data-bind='click: setGenderAndSize.bind($data, "2:2")'>MALE XL</a></li>
    <li><a data-bind='click: setGenderAndSize.bind($data, "2:2")'>FEMALE XS</a></li>
    <li><a data-bind='click: setGenderAndSize.bind($data, "2:2")'>FEMALE S</a></li>
    <li><a data-bind='click: setGenderAndSize.bind($data, "2:2")'>FEMALE M</a></li>
    <li><a data-bind='click: setGenderAndSize.bind($data, "2:2")'>FEMALE L</a></li>
    <li><a data-bind='click: setGenderAndSize.bind($data, "2:2")'>FEMALE XL</a></li>      
  </ul>
</div>
```